# Unable to display errorMessage while trying to enter with same details

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to retrive error message in chrome console from json in backend it is giving default 400 status code

in this code (backend) i have written error messages using conditions these massages are perfectly displaying for backend and used API clients like Postman or VS code's thunder client and getting error messages fine

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const newFaculty = require("../models/SignupModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// register for Faculty

router.post("/signup", async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const { FacultyID, FullName, password } = request.body;

    // validation

    if (!FacultyID || !FullName || !password)
      return response
        .status(400)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Please fill all required fields." });

    if (password.length < 6)
      return response.status(400).json({
        errorMessage: "Please enter a password of at least 6 characters"
      });

    const existingFacultyID = await newFaculty.findOne({ FacultyID });
    if (existingFacultyID)
      return response.status(400).json({
        errorMessage: "An account with this FacultyID already exists"
      });

    // Hash the password

    const saltPassword = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const securePassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltPassword);

    const newFacultyID = new newFaculty({
      FacultyID,
      FullName,
      securePassword,
    });

    const savedFacultyID = await newFacultyID.save();

    // sign using token

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        faculty: savedFacultyID._id,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );

    // send the token in a HTTP only cookie

    response
      .cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .send();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    response.status(500).send();
  }
});

router.post("/login", async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const { FacultyID, password } = request.body;
    

    // validate

    if (!FacultyID || !password)
      return response
        .status(400)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Please enter all required fields." });

    const existingFacultyID = await newFaculty.findOne({ FacultyID });
    if (!existingFacultyID)
      return response
        .status(401)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Wrong Faculty or password." });

    const passwordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
      password,
      existingFacultyID.securePassword
    );
    if (!passwordCorrect)
      return response
        .status(401)
        .json({ errorMessage: "Wrong Id or password." });
    
    // Login using token

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        faculty: existingFacultyID._id,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );

    // send the token in a HTTP only cookie

    response
      .cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .send();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    response.status(500).send();
  }
});

// delete cookie on logout

router.get('/logout', (request, response) => {
  response.cookie("token", "", {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(0)
  }).send();
});

router.get("/loggedIn", (request, response) => {
  try {
    const token = request.cookies.token;
    if (!token) return response.json(false);

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    response.send(true);
  } catch (err) {
    response.json(false);
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

in this frontend code i am trying to register with same details as testing, it showing default 400 bad request but its not displaying actual error message which i have written

```
import React from "react";
import { Paper, withStyles, Grid, TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


const styles = (theme) => ({
  margin: {
    margin: 10,
    marginTop: 100,
    width: 500,
  },
  padding: {
    padding: 25,
  },
  pos: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#7e57c2",
  },
});

class SignUpTab extends React.Component {
  

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      FullName: "",
      FacultyID: "",
      password: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center"
        style={{ padding: 100 }}
      >
        <Paper
          className={classes.padding}
          variant="outlined"
          style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
        >
          <div className={classes.margin}>
            <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.pos}>
               Faculty Signup
            </Typography><br/>
            <Grid container spacing={8} alignItems="flex-end">
              <Grid item md={true} sm={true} xs={true}>
                <TextField
                  id="fullName"
                  label="FullName"
                  type="name"
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  autoFocus
                  required
                  onChange={
                    (this.updateChange = (event) => {
                      this.setState({
                        FullName: event.target.value,
                      });
                    })
                  }
                  value={this.state.FullName}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid container spacing={8} alignItems="flex-end">
              <Grid item md={true} sm={true} xs={true}>
                <TextField
                  id="FacultyID"
                  label="FacultyID"
                  type="name"
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  autoFocus
                  required
                  onChange={
                    (this.updateChange = (event) => {
                      this.setState({
                        FacultyID: event.target.value,
                      });
                    })
                  }
                  value={this.state.EmailID}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Typography>
              <small>faculty ID is faculty registered ID</small>
            </Typography>
            <br />
            <Grid container spacing={8} alignItems="flex-end">
              <Grid item md={true} sm={true} xs={true}>
                <TextField
                  id="password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  required
                  onChange={
                    (this.updateChange1 = (event) => {
                      this.setState({
                        password: event.target.value,
                      });
                    })
                  }
                  value={this.state.password}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Grid container justify="center" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
              <Link
                to={"/faculty"}
                style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#ffffff" }}
              >
                <Button
                  // onClick={routeChange}
                  style={{ background: "#7e57c2" }}
                  onClick={
                    (this.onSubmit = () => {
                      const signup = {
                        FullName: this.state.FullName,
                        FacultyID: this.state.FacultyID,
                        password: this.state.password,
                      };

                      axios
                        .post("http://localhost:4000/app/signup", signup, {
                          withCredentials: true,
                        })
                        .then((response) =>
                          this.setState({ items: response.data })
                        )
                        .catch((err) => {
                          console.log(err);
                        });
                        // .catch((err) => {
                        //   this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message });
                        // });

                      this.setState({
                        FacultyID: "",
                        FullName: "",
                        password: "",
                      });
                    })
                  }
                >
                  <Typography style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}>Sign up</Typography>
                </Button>
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </div>
          <br />
          <Typography className={classes.pos}>
            Already signed in faculty? <Link to={"/faculty"}>login</Link>
          </Typography>
          <br />
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SignUpTab);
```

this is error message i have highlighted in blue box

[image: error message]

Comment: `onClick={ (this.onSubmit = () => {` on click you're creating a function?

Comment: Yes, on click I have written submit function that sends data to backend

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling the function instead of defining it?

Comment: i have written founction inline type.

Comment: I don't see the invokation`()` though... Maybe I missed something

Comment: I have invoked the onSubmit function,and it works all fine. But our problem is the backend,where we cannot give our status code message for error status 400

Comment: For the staus code 400, we are getting "Error: Request failed with status code 409
", even though we are giving our own custom message as "Faculty ID already exists". Please tell me how can I replace it with my own custom message